# SOLVED = The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable

Tags: flutter, image, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

If try to add an imagen in dart-flutter like this, the code may broke

Fo dart version Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.2331

Dart Dart SDK version: 2.17.6

***I solve the Fix using this:***

```
class Movie {
      String? posterAsset;
    
      //Constructor
      Movie({
        this.posterAsset,
      });
    }
    
    child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            //imagen
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage(movie.posterAsset)),
    ],
          ),
    //Inicializador
      MovieMiddle(this.movie);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final bordeSide = BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromARGB(20, 255, 255, 255),
          width: 1,
        );
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            //imagen
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage(movie.posterAsset!)),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

the problem is how call the image is the object is null-safety how you can see here 
 `image: AssetImage(movie.posterAsset!),`

```
return Container(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    //imagen
    children: <Widget>[
      Image(
        image: AssetImage(
          movie.posterAsset!,
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

The most import is, how manage the image:

Fo dart version
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.2331 
Dart Dart SDK version: 2.17.6

[See the picture -> How Prepair and config the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khLtN.png)

[See the picture -> How how implement the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhHrb.png)

Comment: If you have solved your question: Could you write an answer and accept it? That way, the question is not listed as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 1):

It is risky to use `!` directly without null check, you can do

```dart
if( movie.posterAsset!=null) Image(image: AssetImage(movie.posterAsset!))
```

Do a null check, then use the variable like this to all place.